# Jquery Load page 1 div into page 2 div onclick on link with rel

Tags: jquery, ajax, rel

I have made a lot of search on this for hours, read everything i've got... I want to load a div (not the entire page) from page 1 div to page 2 div after a click is made on a link with rel attribute. I do not want to specify the link in the javascript but outside and i want the content of mypage_1_div to be loaded into mypage_2_div.

So far this is what i was able to achieve. Where should i put the mypage_1_div here in the ajax without really adding the link in the ajax because the link must be taken by the ajax on clik on the link with rel attribute ?

```
<a href="index.php" rel="charger">Load Page 1 Div</a> <br><br>

<a href="identification.php" rel="charger">Load Page 3 Div</a> <br><br>


<div id="mypage_2_div"> mypage_2_div </div>

<script>
    $('a[rel*=charger]').click(function() {

    $('#mypage_2_div').html('<img src="images/facebook_style_loader.gif" />');
  $('#mypage_2_div').load($(this).attr('href'));


  return false;
});




</script>
```

Hope i can find help here. Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I just got it. the answer is

```
$('#mypage_2_div').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #mypage_1_div');
```

instead of `$('#mypage_2_div').load($(this).attr('href'));`